# Number Theory or Algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that if $4^m-2^m+1$ is a prime number, then all the prime divisors of $m$ are smaller than $5$

> I initially thought about putting $4^m-2^m+1=p$ where $p$ is some prime and after eliminating initial cases of $p<5$ , setting $p=6k \pm 1$. However, since I'm just a beginner in Number Theory,  I couldn't figure out anything else. What is more surprising that my teacher gave this problem in an Algebra worksheet, so perhaps there is some good algebraic way to do this.
>
> So, thinking on Algebraic lines, I made a substitution $2^m=x$ and did some manipulations to the quadratic thus made. However, still no luck (despite the fact that I'm pretty confident about my Algebraic skills) I look forward for some help with this one. Any (or both) method will do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you studied a little about the ring of Gaussian integers $\;\Bbb Z[i]\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Are you taking about complex numbers?

Comment: Well, a certain *kind* of complex numbers, @Samurai...but if you ask that then you probably hasn't yet studied that cute, thrilling Gaussian integers ring.

Comment: @Samurai, this problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with roots.  Please only use tags which are relevant for your question.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I've mentioned in my question that this was given as a problem in an algebra worksheet to me by my teacher, so it might be connected with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that 
$$
4^m-2^m+1=\frac{8^m+1}{2^m+1}
$$
so that when $m=pq$ is composite, there will be additional factors $4^p-2^p+1$ and $4^q-2^q+1$ to consider.

Comment: How did you notice that $4^m-2^m+1=\frac{8^m+1}{2^m+1}$ and I don't get the rest of your solution??

Comment: @Samurai That's a standard factorization of the polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$. Here we have $x=-2^m$.

Comment: Binomial identites. $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$. Or more generally, $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+b^{n-1}$ and change $b$ to $-b$ if possible. -- Find conditions that all the smaller factors can be absorbed into $2^m+1$.

Comment: @JackM, I'd say $\frac{x^3 + 1}{x + 1} = x^2 - x + 1$

Comment: LutzL, have a plausible conjecture, posted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this problem can most easily be addressed in the Eisenstein integers $R = \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, where $\omega = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}},$ although there may be more elementary approaches. It is well known that this is a principal ideal domain. I claim that
$2^{2m}- 2^{m}+1$ can only be prime (in $\mathbb{Z}$) when $m$ has no prime factor greater than $3,$ as the problem asks. For If not write $m = hn$ where $h >1$ is relatively prime to $6,$ and $2$ and $3$ are the only prime factors of $n.$ Then
$4^{m} -2^{m} + 1 = (2^{m} + \omega)(2^{m} + \omega^{2})$ in $R.$ If $h \equiv 1$ (mod $3$), notice that $\omega^{h} = \omega$, while if $h \equiv 2$ (mod $3$), notice that $\omega^{h} = \omega^{2}.
$ Hence, in the ring $R,$ $2^{m}+ \omega$ is divisible either by $2^{n}+ \omega$ or by $2^{n} + \omega^{2},$ and hence is not a prime element of $R$.Thus $4^{m}-2^{m} +1$ is not a rational prime either.

For the purposes of illustration, the smallest non-trivial case is when $m = 10.$ Then we see by the above method that $2^{10}+\omega$ is divisible by $4+\omega^{2}$ in $R.$ Then we see that  $(4+\omega)(4+\omega^{2}) = 13$ divides $2^{20}-2^{10}+1 = (2^{10}+\omega)(2^{10}+ \omega^{2})$ in $\mathbb{Z}.$  We can check this by verifying directly
that $2^{20} - 2^{10} + 1 \equiv 1- (3 \times 2^{8}) \equiv 1-27 \equiv 0$ (mod $13$) .

Comment: Here we go, Ireland and Rosen, Euclidean domain and UFD page 13, page 110, if $\pi$ is prime then either $N\pi= p$ or $N\pi = p^2$ for rational prime $p.$ Finally, if $N\pi = p$ is a rational prime, then $\pi$ is prime in $\mathbb Z [ \omega ]$

Comment: Yes, thanks, that provides the background if necessary.

Comment: Wow. This answer really opened my eyes to how fields, rings etc. can be used to prove number theoretic theorems. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Taking $A_m = 4^m - 2^m + 1,$ when $m$ is odd we find $A_m \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ anyway.

Apparently, when $n$ is odd and not divisible by $3,$ and for any $k \geq 1,$

$$ A_{2^k} \; | \; A_{2^k n} \; \;.   $$

In defense of this, I have, so far, from the answer by LutzL,
$$ A_{2^k n} = \frac{8^{2^k n} + 1}{2^{2^k n} + 1} = \frac{8^{2^k } + 1}{2^{2^k } + 1} \cdot \frac{\mbox{stuff}}{\mbox{other stuff}} = A_{2^k } \cdot \mbox{integer?}  $$

The output below has $m$ even but not divisible by $3.$ Note that we do have some factors for $A_{160}$ but not for $A_{224}.$ Both should be divisible by $A_{32},$ which is, apparently, prime. Oh, I told the machine to do trial division with primes up to  30,000,000.

One test that can be done without taking very long is to let $m$ get much larger but not divisible by $3,$ and have the values of $A_2, A_4, A_8, A_{16}, A_{32},$ and so on  ready. Without factoring anything, write any $m = 2^k n$ with $n$ odd, then check that $A_m \equiv 0 \pmod {A_{2^k}}.$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
2   13 = 13
4   241 = 241
8   65281 = 97 673
10   1047553 = 13 cdot 61 1321
14   268419073 = 13 cdot 1429 14449
16   4294901761 = 193 22253377
20   1099510579201 = 241  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
22   17592181850113 = 13 cdot 312709 4327489
26   4503599560261633 = 13^2 cdot 313 cdot 1249 cdot 3121 21841     
28   72057593769492481 = 241 cdot 3361  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
32   18446744069414584321 =  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
34   295147905162172956673 = 13 cdot 409 cdot 3061 cdot 13669  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
38   75557863725639445512193 = 13 cdot 131101 cdot 160969  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
40   1208925819613529663078401 = 97 cdot 673  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
44    = 241 cdot 7393  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
46    = 13  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
50    = 13 cdot 61 cdot 1201 cdot 1321 cdot 63901 cdot 13334701  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
52    = 241  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
56    = 97 cdot 673 cdot 2017  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
58    = 13 cdot 349 cdot 29581  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
62    = 13 cdot 373  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
64    = 769  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
68    = 241 cdot 8161  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
70    = 13 cdot 61 cdot 421 cdot 1321 cdot 1429 cdot 14449  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
74    = 13 cdot 3109  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
76    = 241 cdot 90289  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
80    = 193 cdot 23041 cdot 22253377  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
82    = 13 cdot 2953  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
86    = 13 cdot 17029 cdot 46957  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
88    = 97 cdot 673  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
92    = 241  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
94    = 13 cdot 1129 cdot 5641 cdot 1768141  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
98    = 13 cdot 1429 cdot 14449 cdot 540961  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
100    = 241  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
104    = 97 cdot 673 cdot 4993 cdot 94849  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
106    = 13 cdot 10177 cdot 207973  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
110    = 13 cdot 61 cdot 661 cdot 1321 cdot 3301 cdot 8581 cdot 312709 cdot 4327489  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
112    = 193 cdot 22253377  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
116    = 241 cdot 82129  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
118    = 13 cdot 709 cdot 12037 cdot 31153 cdot 5397793  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
122    = 13 cdot 5080081  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
124    = 241 cdot 1489 cdot 29761  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
128    =  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
130    = 13^2 cdot 61 cdot 313 cdot 1249 cdot 1321 cdot 2341 cdot 3121 cdot 21841 cdot 468781  cdot  mbox{BIG}      
134    = 13 cdot 3217 cdot 10453 cdot 132661 cdot 192961  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
136    = 97 cdot 673  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
140    = 241 cdot 3361 cdot 127681 cdot 1130641  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
142    = 13 cdot 853 cdot 189997 cdot 266677 cdot 1396429 cdot 18369973  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
146    = 13 cdot 877 cdot 1013533  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
148    = 241 cdot 92353 cdot 126097 cdot 532801 cdot 854257  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
152    = 97 cdot 673  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
154    = 13 cdot 1429 cdot 14449 cdot 312709 cdot 4327489  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
158    = 13 cdot 151681  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
160    = 26881 cdot 4855681  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
164    = 241  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
166    = 13 cdot 1993 cdot 136453  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
170    = 13 cdot 61 cdot 409 cdot 1321 cdot 3061 cdot 13669 cdot 51001 cdot 15571321  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
172    = 241 cdot 328177 cdot 359137  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
176    = 193 cdot 22253377  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
178    = 13 cdot 2137  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
182    = 13^2 cdot 313 cdot 1249 cdot 1429 cdot 3121 cdot 14449 cdot 21841 cdot 503413 cdot 1948129  cdot  mbox{BIG}      
184    = 97 cdot 673  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
188    = 241  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
190    = 13 cdot 61 cdot 1321 cdot 131101 cdot 160969 cdot 185821 cdot 247381  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
194    = 13 cdot 580837  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
196    = 241 cdot 3361 cdot 84673  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
200    = 97 cdot 673 cdot 4801 cdot 55201  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
202    = 13 cdot 1213 cdot 1896781 cdot 10838917 cdot 12753877  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
206    = 13 cdot 1237  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
208    = 193 cdot 22253377  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
212    = 241 cdot 12721  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
214    = 13 cdot 57781 cdot 1016929  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
218    = 13 cdot 2617 cdot 5233 cdot 9157  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
220    = 241 cdot 7393 cdot 14736481  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
224    =  cdot  mbox{BIG}
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: Suppose $q^i \| A_{2^k}$, then $q>3$. Let $d$ be the order of $2 \pmod{q}$. We have $A_{2^k} \mid 8^{2^{k+1}}-1$ so $d \mid 3(2^{k+1})$. Also for $x=2^{2^k}$, $\gcd(A_{2^k}, 2^{2^{k+1}}-1)=\gcd(x^2-x+1, x^2-1) \mid 3$. Thus $q \nmid 2^{2^{k+1}}-1$ so $d \nmid 2^{k+1}$. This implies $3 \mid d$. Thus $q \nmid 2^{2^{k+1}n}-1$ since $3 \nmid n$. Then $q \nmid 2^{2^kn}+1$. Now $A_{2^k} \mid 8^{2^k}+1 \mid 8^{2^kn}+1$ ($n$ odd) so $q^i \mid 8^{2^kn}+1=(2^{2^kn}+1)A_{2^kn}$. Since $q \nmid 2^{2^kn}+1$, $q^i \mid A_{2^kn}$. Repeat for all $q^i \mid A_{2^k}$. Thus $A_{2^k} \mid A_{2^kn}$.

Comment: @IvanLoh, I like it. Please post as an answer. I have run out of steam myself.

Comment: Well $A_{2^k} \mid A_{2^kn}$ only works for $\gcd(n, 6)=1$, so won't help to solve the problem in its full generality. I do indeed know how to solve the problem, but it is essentially LutzL's approach.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, thanks.